# iOS App build Rejected :- Location Permission modal alert description

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

[image]This dialogue shows up when the location is turned off in device. My App got rejected because of this dialogue does not contain any description on why app requires the location.

I have added all keys in info.plist regarding location usage description.But it doesn't take up the description. This dialogue is not handled by our app and don't know from where it is showing up.

Please guys any help is welcome on why the description does not show up here.? Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: It's simply IN THE PLIST.  they are NOT talking about the description in that alert box.

Comment: If even you don't know how the dialogue is handled, how are we suppose to know and help?

Comment: You need to identify where the dialog is coming from; Check any 3rd party frameworks/modules you are using.

Comment: @Desdenova this shows only when the location is disabled in device settings or else the alert shows up correctly

Comment: @Paulw11 this shows only when the location is disabled in device settings or else the alert shows up correctly

Comment: What do you know, it is an iOS dialog, and an awful one at that; All of the words shouldn't be capitalised.  You should appeal your rejection and explain that it is an iOS dialog that you have no control over; If location services are disabled, Apple Maps shows exactly the same dialog

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an iOS dialog (and a fairly awful one at that; All of the words shouldn't be capitalised).

I would suggest that you appeal your rejection and explain that it is an iOS dialog that you have no control over;

If location services are disabled, Apple Maps shows exactly the same dialog

Comment: Thanks for the help @Paulw11

Answer (score 0):

Add this description with these keys

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Description.</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>Description.</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Description.</string>
```

Apple had mad many changes in permission. If you are asking for NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription. You still need to give a description for NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription.

Comment: I have attached the screen shot of info.plist

Comment: Your info.plist file seems okay. But the alert is from your application. This is not the alert apple ask for the first time.

Comment: This happens only when the location is turned off in device settings. Otherwise the dialogue shows up correctly

Answer (score 0):

This also happened for our app few days back wherein our app was rejected for the similar reasons that you mentioned. The message cannot be a generic one. So you can show a custom screen of yours where you can mention for what exact reasons you need the Location permissions and then show this pop up.

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>MyApp uses your location to provide the list of products serviceable at your location and for better recommendation</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>MyApp uses your location to provide the list of products serviceable at your location and for better recommendation</string>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>MyApp uses your location to provide the list of products serviceable at your location and for better recommendation</string>
```

*Edit:*

Somewhere in your app you might be using this custom messaging with an alert controller

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:title message:**your custom message** preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction *allowAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Settings" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
    }];
    UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
        for (void(^ completion)(NSNumber * __nonnull status) in self.callbacks) {
            completion(@(kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied));
        }
    }];
    [alertController addAction:cancelAction];
    [alertController addAction:allowAction];

    [someViewController presentViewController:alertController animated:animated completion:nil];
```